# File Write Duration on Azure VM with Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, azure, io, windows-server-2012

I recently had to log the time it takes to write a file for some reason. I did this on Windows Server 2012 on an Azure VM. When I looked at the logs, most of the times were 0 ms, only very few were 15.something ms. I thought I did something wrong with the measurement and tested with this piece of code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\TEST";
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            File.WriteAllText(dir + @"\test.txt", "test");
            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan duration = end - start;
            double ms = duration.TotalMilliseconds;
            File.AppendAllText(dir+@"\log.txt", Convert.ToString(ms) + System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Output on my PC (OS locale set to German, so the comma is a decimal mark, not a thousands separator, making the first number 5 ms):

```
5,0037 1,001 0,9976 1,001 1,001 2,002 0,9956 2,002 1,0003 0,9996
```

Output on the remote machine:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And sometimes (OS locale set to English, so the point is the decimal mark, making the relevant number 15.5 ms):

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 15.4914 0 0 0
```

What's the reason for that? Is this some write-cache either on Windows Server 2012 or Azure VM?

Additional info:

- My PC has a single SSD, the remote machine is configured with the OS and Data on seperate drives (not sure what type)

Comment: Is the comma in the PC output a decimal separator, indicating that the writes are taking usually 1 second but up to 5 seconds?  That output seems very unlikely.  BTW 15.4914 is the timer resolution (every TotalMilliseconds will be a multiple of that value).

Comment: To add to Eric's comment I'd suggest using a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch rather than date time.  It is much more accurate.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: Yes the comma in the PC output is a decimal separator (OS locale is German), the numbers are milliseconds. The first value (5 ms) is higher because of the file creation. Does 1-2 ms for writing seem unlikely? Or just if it were seconds? Thanks for the advice for using Stopwatch, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

What drive are you testing this on?  OS Drive/temp drive/attached drive...that matters. As you mentioned the cache setting does matter as well, best to start with attached drive and no cache.

The ALU format size of the drive matters.  For example, if you chunk up the files in 64kb blocks and have 64kb reads/writes that is faster.

Azure drives on storage accounts have a 20 minute warm-up phase where they can be "slow" unitialized or when not used for 20 minutes.

Comment: The PC drive is an SSD where the OS, programs and data are all on that drive. On Azure there's a persistent partition for the OS and programs and a partition for data, which gets swiped with every reboot (I think). I write the file to the user's AppData folder, which is on the same partition as the OS. With ALU format size you mean the cluster size? It's 4096 Bytes per cluster on my PC and the Azure VM as well. Regarding warmup phase: The file write durations on Azure are measured as 0 ms as opposed to 1-2 ms on my PC, so that's not an issue. I'm wondering about the 0 ms.

Comment: Here is a link that talks about calling Flush after writing the text, otherwise it will be in the disk cache (memory): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/06/28/data-series-exploring-windows-azure-drives-disks-and-images.aspx   This might not be the problem since your code uses the File class, which I think does auto flushing...you might want to try to repeat your test with large files that goes over the disk cache and see what numbers you get.